# ios address book similar app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a question friends.Please help me guys. 
I am implementing an ios app which is similar to address book.I am able to display the cells with name and email.I am copying my code below. Anyway my question is I have my names in contactValue.name & emails in contactValue.email.  Now I need to aplhabetize them in to sections. How can I section them.I mean I just want all the names starting with A into one section and so on.

```
id alphabet = [arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

//---get all names beginning with the letter---
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
// How can I filter the names here using the above predicate condition.I have my names in contactValue.name. According to the names the emails should also placed in the cells.


Contact* contactValue= (Contact*)[contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text=contactValue.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=contactValue.email;
```

**@sbooth:  so u mean the following?**  But when I do the following , it says Incomapatible pointer types assigning to NsMutableArray from NsArray at the filtering line of code. What does it mean?

```
   id alphabet = [arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

//---get all states beginning with the letter---
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
//here names n contactArray are NsMutableArrays.

names = [contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if ([names count]>0) {

Contact* contactValue= (Contact*)[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=contactValue.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=contactValue.email;
```

Comment: I think more information would help me understand the problem you're having.  What are you using to display your contact list? In what context is the code above being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all your contacts stored in `contactArray`?  If so, did you try `[contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]`?

Comment: id alphabet = [arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    
    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    
    names = [contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    
          
    if ([names count]>0) {
        
    Contact* contactValue= (Contact*)[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        cell.textLabel.text=contactValue.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=contactValue.email;

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH.
    I am able to come over the issue.I did following:
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSMUtableArray *someArray =(NSMutableArray*)[contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; // Basically casting.
    I hope my answer will help someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. @sbooth, It worked, But the only thing is you just have to cast it.

```
(NSMutableArray*)array  = (NSMutableArray*)[contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```